# Implement a mailing solution in Express nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, nodemailer

I'm creating an API that handles account verification via email, password recovery and possibly other things.

I want to create one place to send emails across my entire API. 
i'm using nodeMailer.

My current setup is i'm a calling a method on the user model that send EmailVerification email.

I want to create a template outside the User model that could send either password recovery, email verification or other things.. Depending on the params that i pass to the function. 
My user model:

```
userSchema.methods.generateEmailVerificationToken = function() {
    const token = jwt.sign({_id: this._id, role: this.role}, 
    config.get('jwtPrivateKey'));
    return token;
};

userSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = function() {
    const token = jwt.sign({_id: this._id, role: this.role}, 
    config.get('jwtPrivateKey'));
    return token;
};

userSchema.methods.sendEmailVerification = function (user) {
sendMail(user);
};
```

and this is my sendMail function:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

module.exports = function sendMail (user) {

    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            user: 'mymail@gmail.com',
            pass: 'mypass'
        }
    });

    const mailOptions = {
        from: 'mymail@gmail.com',
        to: user.email,
        subject: 'Email verification.',
        html:  `Please click this <a href="www.example.com/email_verif/${user.emailVerificationToken}">link</a> to verify your email`
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
        }
    });
}
```

Thank you

Comment: You'll need to show us what you have so far and what errors or issues you are seeing. We can't help otherwise!